# In Qt app how to capture "Cmd-Q" or "Quit" menu click

Tags: macos, qt, qmenu, qevent, qaction

In my Qt app, I have a quit routine which gracefully cleans up everything before finally quitting, else there might be a crash somewhere. The app runs in the system tray, and there is a "Quit" menu defined for the system tray icon. On the quitAction I have set the menu role so that it's merged with Mac's app menu, but I don't see my slot being called. The code is below:

```
QAction *quitAction = new QAction(tr("&Quit"), this);
quitAction->setMenuRole(QAction::QuitRole);
connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(quittingApp()));
```

I have also tried to capture the QCloseEvent on QApplication but even that doesn't seem to work.

```
bool MyApplication::event(QEvent *ev)
{
    bool eaten = false;
    switch (ev->type())
    {
    case QEvent::Close:
    {
        quittingApp(); //My quit cleanup routine
        eaten = true;
        break;
    }
    default:
        eaten = QApplication::event(ev);
        break;
    }
    return eaten;
}
```

Am I missing something here? What's the best way to have my own cleanup routine which is called during quit?

Answer (score -1):

Connecting to the `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit` signal is the best way to perform some last-second cleanup.

Comment: The event loop will be exited immediately after this signal is emitted. But in that case my clean up process won't really complete because it's a step by step cleaning process which needs the event loop to be running.

Comment: @SoumyaDas: You can always spin a local event loop :)

Comment: Anyway, I don't even see the slot connected to QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit signal being called, so I really don't have any clue how to do my own cleanup when the user hits Cmd-Q to quit.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. How does one **specifically** catch the menu Quit command to triage it - perhaps one should not be quitting or other things need taken care of, and so quit needs to be cancelled. One for instance is: catching menu quit as opposed to a subordinate window close button?